# Why 1.66x10e-27 is 1.66e-26

Tags: exponentiation

I am confused with this new way of writing exponential. For example I saw a question where person has changed 1.66X10e-27 to 1.66e-26. I am confused how -27 is reduced to -26
thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Do you simply think that there is an error in the solution? (1.66e-27 and 1.66e-26 are two different things)

Comment: Nope and actually I am confused between 1.66x10e-27 and 1.66e-26

Comment: Please, explain what is confusing you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e-27` is a way of expressing $10^{-27}$ in programming. There is no need for a `10` before it; in fact, putting a `10` before it causes it to be multiplied. So `1.66x10e-27` actually means $1.66 \times 10 \times 10^{-27} = 1.66 \times 10^{-26}$, which is equal to `1.66e-26`.